What's so embarrassing about two people wearing the same jacket?
In Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Miles enters the school and greets fellow students:

Miles: Oh, my gosh! This is embarrassing. We wore the same
jacket.

What's so embarrassing about two people wearing the same jacket?

This joke was in the main theatrical release version.  Its not specific to any alternate version.

I know this is late, and that an answer was already accepted, but I just read it as a joke. Something to break the ice a little bit, get the other students to warm up to him slightly. Just my interpretation.

Being embarrassed about wearing the same clothes to an event is a common issue in media, usually in women but well known enough to be parodied.
Given the setting is a school and they are all wearing uniform, then this is an ironic comment probably used to conceal in inner nervousness about starting at a new school.

"Being embarrassed about wearing the same clothes to an event is a common issue across most of the world." [citation needed]

@O.R.Mapper much of the world might be an exaggeration. But... https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DressesTheSame

Fascinating. It's always a surprise what unexpected customs some subcultures come up with. With that said, note that the TVTropes examples are a wild mixture of this (people being embarrassed due to wearing the same clothes), people embarrassed due to wearing the same costume as someone else (kind of a special case IMHO), people embarrassed not because anyone is wearing the same as them, but because of who is, and all kinds of reactions to someone wearing the same as someone else not due to the sameness, but due to what the clothes imply in terms of rank etc.

@O.R.Mapper it's difficult to point at the start of a thing sometimes, much of the TV tropes page feels like reaching for a rationalisation of what doesn't ever seem to be a rational response at least at the times I've witnessed it in real life.

It's more a high society thing nowadays than anything else.  I've heard a description of preparing for a girl's debutante where the designer and mother discussed where the girl would wear each dress, and the designer took note to make sure that no other girl would get the same dress for the same event.

The usual version is two women wearing the same dress staring at each other and one of them says "Well ONE of us is going to have to go change!"  My understanding is that this being a point of shame comes from the idea that high class clothes are custom orders, and only low class people buy off the rack. If two women showed up to an event in the same dress, then it proved that both of them had been shopping the "lower class" way and so somebody would need to go home and switch dresses to avoid humiliating both of them. Today, nobody much cares.

@Jontia I can't tell you when the beginning was, but it was a joke as far back as when I was in high school in the '80s, and my impression is that the custom goes back at least to the '50s. Perplexity suggests that it dates back to the 19th century: https://www.perplexity.ai/search/when-did-the-custom-of-two-wom-4F6ptCS6TzihVIMF333nUQ#0

From the 1960s musical "This Irresistible Paris Orginal" https://youtu.be/QYOHY4Ik5-g?si=uJ3Tzqw1696phkUr and from the 1950s "I Love Lucy" https://youtu.be/Z0qTN5s1ukA?si=st2qC-wzzRrDlz2q - people upset by duplicate dresses
